# How to read string from a file without using character array?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define     ZERO           (0)
#define     ONE            (1)
#define     TEN            (10)
#define    TWENTY          (20)
#define FOURTY_SEVEN       (47)
#define FIFTY_SEVEN        (57)

typedef struct PHONE
{
 char szName[20] ;

 char szPhone[20] ;

 struct PHONE *pNext ;
};

struct PHONE   *pFirst             = NULL ; // To denote start of the linked list

struct PHONE   *pPointer           = NULL ; // To denote current end node in linked list

struct PHONE   *pNew               = NULL ; // To denote the new node

struct PHONE   *pTemp              = NULL ; // To store pointer temporarily

struct PHONE   *pTempForDeallocation = NULL ; // To store pointer for deallocation

struct PHONE   stPhone            ;

FILE *fPointerForOpen             ;         // To Open the file

int FilePresentOrNot()            ;         // To Check the file is present or not

int MemoryAllocation()            ;         // To Allocate Memory to the Linked List

int main()
{
  int iChoice     = 0 ;

  int iRepeat     = 0 ;

  int iLength     = 0 ;

  do
  {
     fPointerForOpen    = fopen("phonebook.txt","r");

     fflush(stdin);

     system("cls");

     if(NULL == fPointerForOpen)
     {
        FilePresentOrNot();
     }

    // stPhone.szName = (char *)malloc(100);

     while(fscanf(fPointerForOpen,"%s",stPhone.szName)!= EOF)
     {
         fscanf(fPointerForOpen,"%s",stPhone.szPhone);

         pNew = (struct PHONE *) malloc(sizeof(struct PHONE)) ;

         strcpy( pNew -> szName  , stPhone.szName )   ;

         strcpy( pNew -> szPhone , stPhone.szPhone ) ;

         pNew ->pNext = NULL ;

         MemoryAllocation() ;
    }
    printf("\n\nDo you Want to continue then press 1 ? \t");

    scanf("%d",&iRepeat);

    fclose(fPointerForOpen);

    pFirst = NULL ;

}while(ONE == iRepeat);
return 0 ;
}


 int MemoryAllocation()
 {
 if(NULL == pFirst)
  {
    pFirst    = pNew ;

    pPointer  = pNew ;

 }
 else
  {
    pPointer->pNext = pNew ;

    pPointer        = pNew ;

 }
}
```

Here is the code. Here I used array to read name and phone number I want to replace that array into pointers.  When I replaced I can read only four characters only.

Would anyone please help me to do it and please tell me is it correct or not?

Comment: Em... If you want to store a string, which is an array terminated with a null character, then you're going to need an array somehow...

Comment: Pointers point to something. You can make them a `char *` but if you want to store data in that buffer you will need to allocate an array one way or another. In this case it really makes no sense to resource of that, having a structure of fixed size that can be read and written whole makes everything so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your struct with this;

```
  typedef struct PHONE
  {
       char *szName ;
       char *szPhone ;
       struct PHONE *pNext ;
  };
```

Then each time you use a new instance of PHONE, allocate the memory you want;

```
  aPhone.szName = (char *)malloc(sizeOfNameBuffers);
```

or
      pNew->szName = (char *)malloc(sizeOfNameBuffers);

Answer (score 1):

You keep opening and closing the file. Each time you open the file the cursor goes to the beginning of the file, it starts reading line 1 over and over. Try this example instead:

```
struct PHONE
{
    char szName[20];
    char szPhone[20];
    struct PHONE *pNext;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *fPointerForOpen;
    struct PHONE *pFirst = NULL; // To denote start of the linked list
    struct PHONE *pPointer = NULL; // To denote current end node in linked list
    struct PHONE *pNew = NULL; // To denote the new node
    struct PHONE stPhone;

    fPointerForOpen = fopen("phonebook.txt", "r");
    if (!fPointerForOpen)
    {
        printf("cannot read file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while(fscanf(fPointerForOpen, "%s %s", stPhone.szName, stPhone.szPhone) == 2)
    {
        pNew = (struct PHONE*)malloc(sizeof(struct PHONE));
        strcpy(pNew->szName, stPhone.szName);
        strcpy(pNew->szPhone, stPhone.szPhone);
        pNew->pNext = NULL;

        if (!pFirst)
            pFirst = pNew;
        else
            pPointer->pNext = pNew;

        pPointer = pNew;
    } 

    fclose(fPointerForOpen);

    //print the list:
    pPointer = pFirst;
    printf("Testing:\n");
    while (pPointer)
    {
        printf("%s %s\n", pPointer->szName, pPointer->szPhone);
        pPointer = pPointer->pNext;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also try to avoid using global variables when you don't need them. Put the variable in stack as in above example.